# Ubuntu 18.04 grub installation fix on live machine?

Tags: 18.04

when I was installing 18.04 on my laptop grub installation failed , I know there is a bug to be fixed but can it be fixed on the live session ? or on reboot from the grub prompt?

EDIT: how about I install an older version and upgrade ? does that crash grub as well?

Comment: My recommendation is that you make a live disk of Boot-Repair CD and have it fix the grub install.  There is something odd about the grub shipping with 18.04.  Have seen that on a few installs.  Nothing specific  to add to your situation.

Comment: how about I install an older version and upgrade ? does that crash grub as well?